# Difference between two ways of reading an image file as a string

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, image-processing, io

I'm wondering if there's any difference between:

```
encoded_png = open('test.png', 'rb').read()
```

and

```
temp = cv2.imread('test.png')
temp = cv2.cvtColor(temp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
temp3 = tf.io.encode_png(temp)
```

On some test images, it seems like the two string encodings `encoded_png` and `temp3` are not the same, however, passing both encoded strings to `tf.image.decode_png` gave the same results:

```
temp2 = tf.image.decode_png(encoded_jpg, channels=3)
temp4 = tf.image.decode_png(temp3, channels=3)
np.mean(np.abs(temp2-temp4))
```

Does it matter which method is used to encode the images?

Comment: Why would you even consider doing the second one? It introduces 2 additional dependencies (OpenCV and TensorFlow) and requires extra CPU and time to unnecessarily decode, convert and re-encode the image.

Comment: Also, you cannot expect the re-encoded image to match the original bit-for-bit - images often have timestamps and other meta-data embedded that would cause them to differ. And two different encoders might encode the same image differently.

Comment: as long as lossy compression isn't involved (jpg), these should be functionally equivalent.